# Why can I not add more secondary groups?

Tags: 14.04, sudo, groups

I make a group called "teamspeak" and I would then like to be a part of that group, so I use `sudo usermod -a -G teamspeak xdrosenheim` as it is explained [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/) and in the `man usermod`.

I then do `id xdrosenheim` and see nothing has changed, so I log out and log in again.
Now I'm part of the "teamspeak" group, but I lost all the other groups.

```
uid=1000(xdrosenheim) gid=1000(xdrosenheim) groups=1000(xdrosenheim),1002(teamspeak)
```

I am no longer in the sudoers file and need to go to recovery mode :/

So my question is as followed: How do I add a existing user to an existing group?

I guess I could use `usermod -G teamspeak,adm,sudo,moreGroups xdrosenheim` but that would be a very long command in the long run, wouldn't it?

Comment: Did you accidentally run `sudo usermod -G teamspeak xdrosenheim` i.e. forget the `-a`?

Comment: I thought of doing that, but was unsure of it...

Comment: If you run `sudo usermod -a -G teamspeak xdrosenheim` then its all right, but the problem you are having would result if you run `sudo usermod -G teamspeak xdrosenheim`

Comment: This is why I prefer the `gpasswd` command for this kind of thing: `sudo gpasswd --add someuser somegroup`

Answer (score 0):

Better to edit the /etc/group file and added as example below.

```
sudo vim  /etc/group

xdrosenheim:x:1000:xdrosenheim,teamspeak,adm,sudo,moreGroups
```

Comment: Directly editing the file is not a good idea in most circumstances as long as  there are ways to do this via command line..

Comment: of course its not good idea should be care full but you will know what you are doing more over XDRosenheim does not like to run long commands ;-)

Comment: I don't have a problem with long commands, it's just that if I at some point have over 20 groups, then I would have to type them again, and again, and again... :)